# Text widget not updating inside StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting a QuerySnapShot from a Firestore subcollection inside a StreamBuilder from another query, as follows:

```
  //ver fuegos
                              var estePost = listaFiltrada[indexPost].post_id;
                              int numero_fuegos = 0;
                              FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                  .collection('posts')
                                  .doc(estePost)
                                  .collection('fuegos')
                                  .get()
                                  .then((value) => {
                                        if (value.size > 0)
                                          {
                                            setState(() {
                                              numero_fuegos = value.size;
                                            }),
                                            print("tiene fuegos: " +
                                                numero_fuegos.toString()),
                                          }
                                        else
                                          {
                                            setState(() {
                                              numero_fuegos = value.size;
                                            }),
                                          }
                                  });
```

There are 3 items for value.size.

Here you have the print output:

```
 I/flutter (29797): tiene fuegos: 3
```

The issue is that putting the variable numero_fuegos inside a text widget, the output is always 0.

[image]

EDIT:

```
class ListaPosts extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListaPostsState createState() => _ListaPostsState();
}

class _ListaPostsState extends State<ListaPosts> {
  String _miId = "";

  @override
  initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    FirebaseAuth.instance.idTokenChanges().listen((User user) {
      if (user == null) {
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _miId = user.uid;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final postsProvider = Provider.of<PostsProvider>(context);

    return Container(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            StreamBuilder<List<Post>>(
                stream: postsProvider.posts,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.data != null &&
                      snapshot.data.isNotEmpty &&
                      ConnectionState.done != null) {
                    List<Post> listaInicial = snapshot.data;
                    List<Post> listaFiltrada = [];
                    listaFiltrada = listaInicial;

                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 140,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: listaFiltrada.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, indexPost) {
                              bool es_ambassador = listaFiltrada[indexPost]
                                  .post_autor_is_ambassador;

                              //ver fuegos
                              var estePost = listaFiltrada[indexPost].post_id;
                              int numero_fuegos = 0;
                              FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                  .collection('posts')
                                  .doc(estePost)
                                  .collection('fuegos')
                                  .get()
                                  .then((value) => {
                                        if (value.size > 0)
                                          {

                                              numero_fuegos = value.size,

                                            print("tiene fuegos: " +
                                                numero_fuegos.toString()),
                                            print("tiene fuegos: " +
                                                value.size.toString()),
                                          }
                                        else
                                          {
                                            setState(() {
                                              numero_fuegos = value.size;
                                            }),
                                          }
                                      });
```

And that is the Stream:

```
  //Get Posts Entries
  Stream<List<Post>> getPosts() {
    return _db
        .collection('posts')
        .orderBy("post_fecha", descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) =>
            snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Post.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());
  }
```

Comment: post your `State.build` method, what `Stream` are you passing to `StreamBuilder`?

Comment: @pskink, I will update my question to add what you need.

Comment: most likely `PostsProvider.posts` does not trigger any events

Comment: @pskink, I don't understand  the relationship between PostProvider.post events in that case

Comment: @pskink, do you need the code for PostProvider?

Comment: `StreamBuilder.stream` is a stream with your data, each time that `Stream` triggers new data it rebuilds `StreamBuilder` by calling `build` method - see one minute introduction here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkKEWHfy99Y

Comment: @pskink, yes I know that, but on each time the Stream triggers new data, the QuerySnapShot is also created, it is right? I am getting the correct value as the print output demonstrates, I don't really understand why the print  output is updated but not the text widget

Comment: yes, i think so, if you see `print` output but no change in `Text` widget it means that `StreamBuilder.builder` callback is not called: to check it just add `print(snapshot);` just after: `builder: (context, snapshot) {`

Comment: @pskink, do you think I should create another indepent collection for storing the data and not inside a subcollection?

Comment: @pskink, in other words, what should I do to combine the current streambuilder and other QuerySnapShots?

Comment: @pskink, this is the output for  print("este es el snapshot:"+snapshot.toString()); just below builder:(context,snapshot):  I/flutter (29797): este es el snapshot:AsyncSnapshot<List<Post>>(ConnectionState.waiting, [Instance of 'Post'], null)
I/flutter (29797): numero de fuegos mas abajo:0
Reloaded 6 of 1296 libraries in 2,446ms.
I/flutter (29797): tiene fuegos: 3
I/flutter (29797): tiene fuegos: 3
I/flutter (29797): este es el snapshot:AsyncSnapshot<List<Post>>(ConnectionState.active, [Instance of 'Post'], null)